# netplan - match physical ifs only

Tags: 20.04, netplan

I'm using `netplan` on 20.04 (Focal) and would like to match only physical ifs in one of the stanzas.

if I use:

```
ethernets:
  dmz0:
    match:
      macaddress: b8:a3:86:70:cc:e6
      name: dmz*|en*
    set-name: dmz0
```

it complains `Cannot find unique matching interface for dmz0` and doesn't match, and if I don't have the `name` match it does the same once the v-devs are created.

```
$ ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: dmz0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:a3:86:70:cc:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:25:df:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The matching (without `name`) is working on boot-up, which is how I got the i/f names I need to be able to create the firewall rules etc.

The matching (either way) doesn't work later (`netplan try|apply`) as the VLans and bridges adopt the same MAC Address as the physical interface.  I need this resetting of the netplan config as services (with the associated v-devs) come and go.

Any advice for how to achieve a stable, repeatable match?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly found matching on `macaddress` alone is not enough, if `vlans` are configured (and take the same MAC address).

Unfortunately, netplan does not support full RegEx matching at this time, but only shell-style glob matching. Therefore, the `"|"` operator in your name match does not work as intended and the interfaces cannot be found. There is currently an open pull request to improve this situation for `driver` and `name` matching in the future: https://github.com/canonical/netplan/pull/202

For now you would probably need to split up your match into two, to achieve the intended effect:

```
ethernets:
  id0:
    match:
      macaddress: b8:a3:86:70:cc:e6
      name: dmz*
    set-name: dmz0
  id1:
    match:
      macaddress: b8:a3:86:70:cc:e6
      name: en*
    set-name: dmz0
```

Comment: FYI, you can now match with multiple `driver` globs. The linked PR#202 shipped with [netplan 0.104](https://github.com/canonical/netplan/releases/tag/0.104) which is available on Ubuntu 20.04 via focal-updates.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a bit old and probably you found a solution already and moved on. Here is just for future me as a reference:

What worked best for me is to use `driver` in matching as well. As physical interfaces have a different driver to virtual ones. Here some examples from my servers.

```yml
# /etc/netplan/01-persistent-net.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:bc:80:f4
        driver: vmxnet3
      set-name: ens160
```

or

```yml
# /etc/netplan/01-persistent-net.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    intf_eth2:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:68:05:6a
        driver: r8152
      set-name: intf_eth2
    intf_eth3:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:68:0e:95
        driver: r8152
      set-name: intf_eth3
```