# How to get driver udev property for netplan match?

Tags: systemd-networkd

I want to use `match` in my netplan config, but if I attach a vlan to an interface I can no longer match by the mac address of that interface alone. See [netplan - match physical ifs only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326021/netplan-match-physical-ifs-only)

Proposed solution is to `match` the `driver` as well as the `macaddress`.

From the [netplan docs](https://netplan.io/reference/),

```
match (mapping)
This selects a subset of available physical devices by various hardware
properties. The following configuration will then apply to all matching
devices, as soon as they appear. All specified properties must match.

name (scalar)
...
macaddress (scalar)
...
driver (scalar or sequence of scalars) – sequence since 0.104
Kernel driver name, corresponding to the DRIVER udev property.
A sequence of globs is supported, any of which must match.
Matching on driver is only supported with networkd.
```

so I need to know the DRIVER udev property. But where can I find that?

I found [udev_device_get_driver](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libudev-dev/udev_device_get_driver.3.en.html) but I've never worked with C headers like this and I'm not sure what I would give it as an input (`struct udev_device *udev_device`)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your interfaces with `ip a` and you find the one you want to `match` in netplan.

The name of this interface shall be `$NAME`.

`udevadm info -a /sys/class/net/$NAME`

In the output of this there should be:

`looking at device /devices/.../foo/net/$NAME`

which has `DRIVER` defined as an empty string.

and then `looking at parent device /devices/.../foo`

which has `DRIVER` defined. **This is what you can refer to in your netplan config.**